# How to switch from one view controller to another in a chain

Tags: ios6, ios7, uiviewcontroller

I have a initial view controller, from which i need to push to first view controller. on back click of first view controller instead of going back to initial view controller i need to go to a third view controller. from back click on third view controller it should go back to initial view controller. Could anyone suggest me how to do it in ios6 and also in ios7.

Answer (score 0):

Call `setViewControllers:animated:` after the push, to insert the middle view controller into the stack.

Comment: You are wrong. Of course you can crash if you call it wrong. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/Documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#jumpTo_21

Answer (score 0):

there are many other way to do but i prefer this one:

for that you have to add programmatically navigation bar button as "back" at first view controller(in your case) but in this case you required back_arrow image:

```
UIImage *faceImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"back_arrow.png"];
UIButton *face = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
face.bounds = CGRectMake( 10, 0, faceImage.size.width, faceImage.size.height );
[face addTarget:self action:@selector(handleBack) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[face setImage:faceImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:face];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButton;
[self.navigationItem setHidesBackButton:YES animated:YES];
[self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:nil animated:NO];
[self.navigationItem setBackBarButtonItem:nil];

-(void)handleBack
{
  //got third view controller here
}
```

may it will help you.